# How do I make RadioButton and TextField disappear?

Tags: javafx

Hi l want to make  RadioButton and TextField disappear After the user completes the required data so that he or she will replace it as a result of the test

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Please try to edit your question to provide a [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `radioButton.setVisible(false); textField.setVisible(false);`

Comment: Depends on the ancestors and the way you want the versions of the scene to look. Setting the visibility is one option, but it may not work in all cases. Removing the node from the parent is another one...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`setVisible(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setVisible-boolean-) methods on an `Node` to hide your elements. Your code would look like this, assuming your radio button is named `radioButton` and your text field `textField`, respectively.

```java
radioButton.setVisible(false);

textField.setVisible(false);
```